# How do I integrate Neo4j database with Tcl?

Tags: interface, neo4j, tcl

I have a Tcl program that uses a database: SQLite.

```
package require sqlite3
```

I can run sql queries like this:

```
sqlite3 brain "./brain/$id.sqlite" -create true
brain eval { create table if not exists main(time char, input char) }

#generic update
proc ::repo::update::onId {table column data id} {
    brain eval "UPDATE '$table' SET '$column'='$data' WHERE rowid='$id'"
}
```

Which has served me well, but I think making a graphical representation of my data would be useful now.

Does anyone know how I can use Tcl to interact with the Neo4j database?

Someone suggested I make my own driver and pointed me towards these links, but I'm not a programmer so I'm having difficulty figuring out what I need to do. I am willing to do this if I can figure out how, I've just never done anything like it before.

existing tcl driver? I'm not sure what this is. https://github.com/ekzemplaro/data_base_language/blob/master/neo4j/tcl/read/neo4j_read.tcl

API interface: http://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/3.1/http-api/#http-api-transactional

Would I just write a driver that sends post messages like this?

> POST http://localhost:7474/db/data/transaction/12

```
{
  "statements" : [ {
    "statement" : "CREATE (n) RETURN n"
  } ]
}
```

Thanks for whatever help or advice you can offer me!

Comment: You've been ever so lucky; your code is unsafe as it has potential SQL injection vulnerabilities. It's also syntactically invalid, but in ways that SQLite silently allows. (OTOH, that's not what your question is about…)

Comment: no, I appreciate that, Donal Fellows, I haven't really been concerned with security at all with this system because it's just a proof of concept and I'm the only one using it right now. But yes if I ever want to take it to the next level I'll have to definitely fix those issues, but for now since it works well enough I haven't even considered cleaning up the sql queries.

Comment: Let's just say that `Mr. O'Neill` is a very useful tester with any database; he's known to work with [Bobby Tables](https://xkcd.com/327/)…